How to Display UTF-8 Characters using Javascript or jQuery?
I am trying to cycle through all of the Zodiac signs using JavaScript/jQuery.
Is there a way to do this by just counting up and then displaying that character?
At first I tried this using the &#XXXX way of writing the characters, but they would not be converted to their respective Unicode character, but instead displayed literally.
Then I tried using u\XXXX but I got the Error: "malformed Unicode character escape sequence". Here is my code:
setInterval(changeZodiac, 200);

var whichZodiac = 9800;

function changeZodiac() {
    var hexZodiac = whichZodiac.toString(16);
    console.log(hexZodiac);
    $("#zodiac").text("\u" + hexZodiac);
    whichZodiac++;
    if (whichZodiac > 9811) {
        whichZodiac = 9800;
    }
}

The error feels like it is there to prevent a problem if something like this happens accidentally. But is there a way to make this work intentionally?

Try "\\u" + ...

This has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Use html() instead of text():


var whichZodiac = 9800;
function changeZodiac() {
    $("#zodiac").html("&#" + whichZodiac + ";");
    if (++whichZodiac > 9811) whichZodiac = 9800;
}

setInterval(changeZodiac, 200);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zodiac"></div>




Thank you so much man. It works perfectly.

@Jaron you should accept this answer by clicking ✔

Don't create a string with an escape sequence and then try to parse it. Just use String.fromCharCode to directly get the character:


var whichZodiac = 9800;
function changeZodiac() {
    document.getElementById("zodiac").textContent = String.fromCharCode(whichZodiac);
    if (++whichZodiac > 9811) whichZodiac = 9800;
}

setInterval(changeZodiac, 200);
<div id="zodiac"></div>



